# Sharing Resource (Resx) file as a linked item in different projects across solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, embedded-resource

I have a solution named 'MyApplication' with two projects:

ProjectA (namespace MyApplication.ProjectA) {.Net Core 2.1}
ProjectB (namespace MyApplication.ProjectB) {.Net Core 2.1 Test Project}

ProjectA contains a resource file named 'Messages.resx'.

I have Messages.resx **Add As Link** in ProjectB and whenever I am reading value from Messages.resx in ProjectB it is throwing **System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException**.
I don't want to directly reference ProjectA inside ProjectB. Also adding a third library project with Resource file in it and referring it in both ProjectA and ProjectB is not an option.
How can I add resource as Add As Link and consume it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, I have two mvc projects: WebApplication1 and WebApplication3.

And I have a Resource file(MyData.resx) in WebApplication3:

[image]

MyData.resx:

[image]

Now, based on your needs, I have MyData.resx Add as link in WebApplication1:

[image]

Then, I can get the data from the .rexs file in WebApplication1 controller like below:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var rm = new ResourceManager("WebApplication1.Resources.MyData", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        string username = rm.GetString("Username");
        return View();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Note: the baseName in the ResourceManager should be the current project namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. **Key thing was the base name**. I was using the base name of actual project where my resource file is kept.
I was just wondering if there was any way I could directly get values from my resource file in project where resource file is added as a link, without having to use Resource Manager. Like if I could do MyData.UserName direclty inside WebApplication1, just as to avoid strongly typed key names which we are doing when retrieving values from ResourceManager.