# Included .resx file throws error when containing project is referenced from other project (.NET 6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two projects: Project A (ASP.NET Core web app) and Project B (Console app).

In project A I have a `.resx` file with translated strings I want the data annotations to use (like Required etc.). When I try to reference project A from other projects (in this case I tried with project B as a test), I get the error **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid manifest format. 'ResourcePath' must contain a text value. '''** as seen here:

[image: Screenshot of error]

The calling code (in proj. B) is:

```
var f = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(DataAnnotationStrings).Assembly);
```

In my .csproj file, I have the following included:

```
<GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
```

I have searched for any and every article I could find about this subject, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125744/sharing-resource-resx-file-as-a-linked-item-in-different-projects-across-solut)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ExcludeFromManifest="true"` to your localized resource file in the csproj. See example below.

The embedded manifest file provider by default includes all embedded resources in it.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
    <EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>false</EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="TextResources\*.txt" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Localization\Resources\SomeResource.en.resx" ExcludeFromManifest="true" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Sources: 
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1333 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/31107/files

Comment: That solved that problem partly. Now I can include the .resx file in Project B, but I can't override the file (thereby setting new strings) in Project B.